# Code coverage for rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, code-coverage

I am rather new to rails, and I am using rspec to write unit tests, integration tests and functional tests.

We want to integrate TDD in our team. While it is a great way to plan how to write functionality, for me it doesn't feel at all like a proper unit test, when it comes to code coverage.

I would like to have insight in the coverage of our unit tests. If I write a method, it should be tested in such a way that the following is ensured:

- Every line of code is executed
- Every outcome of boolean expressions (e.g. in `if`/`unless` statements) is produced during the test.

I want to be able to get insight in how my tests are doing in terms of these two requirements, i.e. to see my code and see what lines and expressions are being tested and which are not. Is there a tool / gem that you could recommend me that gives me this information?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is exactly what you are looking for: 
https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov

Comment: Don't forget to use `SimpleCov.start 'rails'` so SimpleCov uses a special configuration for Rails projects :)